# Multitexturing theory with texture objects and samplers

Tags: opengl, textures

I couldn't find any good theory articles on how to code multitexturing with either only texture objects or texture objects plus samplers. I just don't know how to manage the glActiveTexture function and what it exactly does.

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0); // Number between 0 and GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, img.getSize().x, img.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.getPixelsPtr()); // Not in sampler
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Not in sampler

/* Values associated with the texture and not with sampler (sampler has priority over texture).
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);*/

glGenSamplers(1, &textureSampler);
glBindSampler(0, textureSampler);
glSamplerParameteri(textureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glSamplerParameteri(textureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glSamplerParameteri(textureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glSamplerParameteri(textureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(colorShader->program, "textureSampler"), 0); // 0 pour GL_TEXTURE0
```

I'm a little bit confused about if multitexturing is about having multiple samplers in the fragment code linked to multiple textures or if it is possible to have only have one sampler with multiple textures?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Much of this must have been explained before, but let me try and give an overview that will hopefully make it clearer how all the different pieces fit together. I'll start by explaining each piece separately, and then explain how they are connected.

#### Texture Target

This refers to the different types of textures (2D, 3D, etc). You can have multiple textures, one of each texture type, bound to the same texture unit at the same time. For example, after:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texId2);
```

**Both**`texId1` and `texId2` will be bound to the same texture unit, which is possible because they are bound to different targets.

The details of this are somewhat convoluted and confusing, and I won't consider it in the rest of this answer. I would recommend that you always bind different textures to different texture units. It will save you from headaches and surprises.

#### Texture Object

Names for texture objects are created with `glGenTextures()`, they are bound with `glBindTexture()`, etc. Texture objects own:

- Texture data.
- State that defines how the texture data is sampled, like filtering attributes set with `glTexParameteri()`.

They also contain information about the texture format/type that was specified together with the data.

#### Texture Unit

As part of the current OpenGL state, you can picture a table of textures that are currently bound. We need more than a single texture bound at the same time to support multi-texturing. A texture unit can be seen as an entry in this state table.

You use `glActiveTexture()` to specify the currently active texture units. Calls that need to operate on a specific texture unit will then operate on the active texture unit. For example:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
```

Will bind `texId` to texture unit 3. Picturing the table of bound textures again, the 4th entry (numbering starts at 0) now points at the texture `texId`.

#### Sampler Object

This is a newer kind of object available in OpenGL 3.3 and later. You will **not** need this for most use cases, even if they involve sampling from multiple textures. I'm including them here for completeness, but there's no need to worry about samplers until you have a firm grasp of texture objects and texture units.

Remember how I explained above that texture objects own the texture data, as well as state that defines how the data is sampled? What samplers essentially do is decouple these two aspects. The sampler object contains state that can override the sampling related state in the texture object.

What this allows you to do is sample **one single texture** with **different sampling parameters** in the same shader. Say you wanted to do LINEAR and NEAREST sampling of the same texture in a single shader. Without sampler objects, you can't do that without having multiple copies of the same texture (with multiple copies of the data). Sampler objects enable this kind of functionality.

#### Texture View

This is a feature introduced in OpenGL 4.3. Even more than texture samplers, I'm only mentioning it for completeness.

Where samplers decouple the texture data (with its associated format) from the sampling parameters, texture views decouple the raw texture data from the format. They make it possible to use the same raw texture data with different formats. I suspect that you can go a very long way without ever using this feature.

#### Putting the Pieces Together

What you ultimately want to do is specify which textures a shader should sample from. Texture units are the critical pieces in making the connection between shaders and textures.

Looking at it from the side of the shader, the shader knows which texture units it samples from. This is given by the value of the sampler uniform variables. For example, if "MyFirstTexture" is the name of a sampler variable in the shader code, the following specifies that the variable is associated with texture unit 3:

```
GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "MyFirstTexture");
glUniform1i(loc, 3);
```

The association between texture unit and a texture object is established with the code fragment that was already shown above:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
```

These two pieces are the critical parts in connecting a texture to a sampler variable in your shader code. Note that the value of the uniform variable is the index of the texture unit (`3`), while the argument of `glActiveTexture()` is the corresponding enum (`GL_TEXTURE3`). I would argue that this is unfortunate API design, but you'll just have to get used to it.

Once you understand this, it will hopefully be very obvious how you use multiple textures in your shader (aka "multi-texturing"):

- You have multiple sampler variables in your shader code.
- You make the `glUniform1i()` calls to set the values of the sampler variables to indices of different texture units.
- You bind a texture to each of the matching texture units.

Showing this for two texture, using texture units 0 and 1:

```
glUseProgram(prog);

GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "MyFirstTexture");
glUniform1i(loc, 0);
loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "MySecondTexture");
glUniform1i(loc, 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId1);
```

One other way of looking at this is that there's a level of indirection between samplers variables in shaders, and texture objects. The shader does not have a direct connection to the texture objects. Instead, it has an index into a table of texture objects (where this index is the value of the uniform variable), and this table in turn contains "pointers" to texture objects (where the table entries are populated with `glActiveTexture()/`glBindTexture()`.

Or one final analogy for the same thing, using communication terminology: You can look at the texture units as ports. You tell the shader which ports to read data from (value of uniform variable). Then you plug a texture into the port (by binding it to the texture unit). The shader will now read data from the texture you plugged into the port.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default sampler object contained in each texture object that will be used to read from the texture when no sampler object is bound to the corresponding sampler unit. To modify the parameters of this object, similar glTexParameter function are provided.