# OpenGL texture terminology/conceptual confusion

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've found a lot of resources that tell you what to type to get a texture on screen, but would like a higher level conceptual understanding of what the openGL API is "doing" and what all of the differences in terminology "mean".

I'm going to do my best to explain what I've picked up, but would love any corrections/additions, or pointers to resources where I can read further (and just a note that I've found the documentation of the actual API calls to just reference themselves in circles and be conceptually lacking).

`glGenTextures`- this won't actually allocate any memory for the data of a texture on the graphics card (you just tell it "how many" textures you want it to generate, so it doesn't know anything about the size...), but instead sets kind of a "name" aside so you can reference given textures consistently (I've been thinking of it as kind of "allocating a pointer").

`glBindTexture`- use the "name" generated in `glGenTexture` to specify that "we're now talking about this texture for future API calls until further notice", and further, we're specifying some metadata about that "pointer" we've allocated saying whether the texture it points to (/will point to) is of type `GL_TEXTURE_2D` or `..._3D` or whatever. (Is it just me, or is it weird that this call has those two seemingly totally different functionalities?)

`glTexParameter`- sets other specified metadata about the currently "bound" texture. (I like this API as it seems pretty self explanatory and lets you set metadata explicitly... but I wonder why letting OpenGL know that it's a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` isn't part of THIS call, and not the previous? Especially because you have to specify that it's a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` every time you call this anyways? And why do you have to do that?)

`glTexImage2D`- allocates the memory for the actual data for the texture on the graphics card (and optionally uploads it). It further specifies some metadata regarding how it ought be read: its width, height, formatting (`GL_RGB`, `GL_RGBA`, etc...). Now again, why do I *again* have to specify that it's a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` when I've done it in all the previous calls? Also, I guess I can understand why this includes some metadata (rather than offloading ALL the texture metadata calls to `glTexParameter` as these are pretty fundamental/non-optional bits of info, but there are also some weird parameters that seem like they oughtn't have made the cut? oh well...)

`glActiveTexture`- this is the bit that I really don't get... So I guess graphics cards are capable of having only a limited number of "texture units"... what is a texture unit? Is it that there can only be N texture buffers? Or only N texture pointers? Or (this is my best guess...) there can only be N pointers being actively read by a given draw call? And once I get that, where/how often to I have to specify the "Active Texture"? Does `glBindTexture` associate the bound texture with the currently active texture? Or is it the other way around (bind, then set active)? Or does uploading/allocating the graphics card memory do that?

`sampler2D`- now we're getting into glsl stuff... So, a sampler is a thing that can reference a texture from within a shader. I can get its location via `glGetUniformLocation`, so I can set which texture that sampler is referencing- does this correspond to the "Active Texture"? So if I want to talk about the texture I've specified as `GL_TEXTURE0`, I'd call `glUniform1i(location_of_sampler_uniform,0)`? Or are those two different things?

I think that's all I got... if I'm obviously missing some intuition or something, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: A texture unit is a very hardware-centric concept. The easiest way to think about it is a "processor" on the GPU that handles a set of texture computations. It's one of many pathways through the texture processing hardware. In most cases, you shouldn't need to work with glActiveTexture(), as it should be seamless from your point of view. The reason glActiveTexture() is included in the API is to allow you to do hardware specific optimizations like keeping all your textures on a single texture unit, but even if you don't access it the GL driver *should* handle the texture management for you.

Comment: @Phildo: maye this [diagram](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heinm/tmp/texture_units.pdf) helps a bit.

Comment: @stix: if I don't need to use glActiveTexture, how do I specify to my uniform sampler2D which texture it ought be referencing? Should the int value I set it to instead be the int generated by glGenTextures? @ derhass: that does help- thanks! But I still feel like I'm missing the complete picture...

Comment: I tried to explain some of the terminology in a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960403/multitexturing-theory-with-texture-objects-and-samplers/30961114#30961114.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Let me apologize for answering with what amounts to a giant wall of text. I could not figure out how to format this any less obnoxious way ;)*

> **glGenTextures**
>
> > this won't actually allocate any memory for the data of a texture on the graphics card (you just tell it "how many" textures you want it to generate, so it doesn't know anything about the size...), but instead sets kind of a "name" aside so you can reference given textures consistently (I've been thinking of it as kind of "allocating a pointer").

You can more or less think of it as "allocating a pointer." What it really does is reserve a name (handle) in the set of textures. Nothing is allocated at all at this point, basically it just flags GL to say "you can't hand out this name anymore." *(more on this later)*.

---

> **glBindTexture**
>
> > use the "name" generated in glGenTexture to specify that "we're now talking about this texture for future API calls until further notice", and further, we're specifying some metadata about that "pointer" we've allocated saying whether the texture it points to (/will point to) is of type GL_TEXTURE_2D or ..._3D or whatever. (Is it just me, or is it weird that this call has those two seemingly totally different functionalities?)

If you will recall, `glGenTextures (...)` only reserves a name. This function is what takes the reserved name and effectively finalizes it as a texture object (the first time it is called). The type you pass here is immutable, once you bind a name for the first time, it has to use the same type for every successive bind.

Now you have finally finished allocating a texture object, but it has no data store at this point -- it is just a set of states with no data.

---

> **glTexParameter**
>
> > sets other specified metadata about the currently "bound" texture. (I like this API as it seems pretty self explanatory and lets you set metadata explicitly... but I wonder why letting OpenGL know that it's a GL_TEXTURE_2D isn't part of THIS call, and not the previous? Especially because you have to specify that it's a GL_TEXTURE_2D every time you call this anyways? And why do you have to do that?)

I am actually not quite clear what you are asking here -- maybe my explanation of the previous function call will help you? But you are right, this function sets the state associated with a texture object.

---

> **glTexImage2D**
>
> > allocates the memory for the actual data for the texture on the graphics card (and optionally uploads it). It further specifies some metadata regarding how it ought be read: its width, height, formatting (GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, etc...). Now again, why do I again have to specify that it's a GL_TEXTURE_2D when I've done it in all the previous calls? Also, I guess I can understand why this includes some metadata (rather than offloading ALL the texture metadata calls to glTexParameter as these are pretty fundamental/non-optional bits of info, but there are also some weird parameters that seem like they oughtn't have made the cut? oh well...)

This is what allocates the data store and (optionally) uploads texture data (you can supply `NULL` for the data here and opt to finish the data upload later with `glTexSubImage2D (...)`).

You have to specify the texture target here because there are half a dozen different types of textures that use 2D data stores. The simplest way to illustrate this is a cubemap.

A cubemap has type `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, but you cannot upload its texture data using `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` -- that is nonsensical. Instead, you call `glTexImage2D (...)` while the cubemap is bound to `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` and then you pass something like `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X` to indicate which of the 6 2D faces of the cubemap you are referencing.

---

> **glActiveTexture**
>
> > this is the bit that I really don't get... So I guess graphics cards are capable of having only a limited number of "texture units"... what is a texture unit? Is it that there can only be N texture buffers? Or only N texture pointers? Or (this is my best guess...) there can only be N pointers being actively read by a given draw call? And once I get that, where/how often to I have to specify the "Active Texture"? Does glBindTexture associate the bound texture with the currently active texture? Or is it the other way around (bind, then set active)? Or does uploading/allocating the graphics card memory do that?

This is an additional level of indirection for texture binding (GL did not always have multiple texture units and you would have to do multiple render passes to apply multiple textures).

Once multi-texturing was introduced, binding a texture actually started to work this way:

```
glBindTexture (target, name)  =>  ATIU.targets [target].bound = name

Where:

  * ATIU is the active texture image unit
  * targets is an array of all possible texture types that can be bound to this unit
  * bound is the name of the texture bound to ATIU.targets [target]
```

The rules since OpenGL 3.0 have been, you get a minimum of 16 of these for every shader stage in the system.

This requirement allows you enough binding locations to maintain a set of 16 different textures for each stage of the programmable pipeline (vertex,geometry,fragment -- 3.x, tessellation control / evaluation -- 4.0). Most implementations can only use 16 textures in a single shader invocation (pass, basically), but you have a total of 48 (GL3) or 80 (GL4) places you can select from.

---

> **sampler2D**
>
> > now we're getting into glsl stuff... So, a sampler is a thing that can reference a texture from within a shader. I can get its location via glGetUniformLocation, so I can set which texture that sampler is referencing- does this correspond to the "Active Texture"? So if I want to talk about the texture I've specified as GL_TEXTURE0, I'd call glUniform1i(location_of_sampler_uniform,0)? Or are those two different things?

Yes, the samplers in GLSL store indices that correspond to `GL_TEXTUREn`, where **n** is the value you have assigned to this uniform.

These are not regular uniforms, mind you, they are called [opaque types](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Opaque_types) (the value assigned cannot be changed/assigned from within a shader at run-time). You do not need to know that, but it might help to understand that if the question ever arises:

"Why can't I dynamically select a texture image unit for my sampler at run-time?" :)

In later versions of OpenGL, samplers actually became [state objects of their own](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object). They decouple some of the state that used to be tied directly to texture objects but had nothing to do with interpreting how the texture's data was stored. The decoupled state includes things like texture wrap mode, min/mag filter and mipmap levels. *Sampler objects store no data.*

This decoupling takes place whenever you bind a sampler object to a texture image unit - that will override the aforementioned states that are duplicated by every texture object.

So effectively, a GLSL `sampler*` references neither a texture nor a sampler; it references a texture image unit (which may have one or both of those things bound to it). GLSL will pull sampler state and texture data accordingly from that unit based on the declared `sampler` type.